# Xcode missing after installation

Tags: xcode, installation

I recently reinstalled my mac. Tried installing Xcode from a backup installer I had  (xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg). It stopped in between asking me to stop iTunes. Did that but the prompt refused to go off. So I was forced to terminate the installer forcefully. (only later did I find out that you had to stop the ituneshelper process from the activity monitor)

Restarted the machine and tried the installation again. The installation when through fine but I was unable to find the Xcode executable anywhere. So I installed it again... no go. Finally I deleted the developer folder and tried it again. Didnt work.

Whats wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try a Spotlight search for 'XCode'?

Comment: Yup. First thing I did. The xcode app is not present in the developer/application folder.

Comment: Why do you not just install Xcode from the Mac App Store? Or are you set on using Xcode 3?

Comment: @mattjgalloway: Nothing like that. I just wanted to avoid the 1.4 gb download.

Comment: Also... whats the guarantee that it will work? How do I remove the partial installation before installing 4.0? Delete the developer folder?

Comment: Newer versions of Xcode live in /Applications and can exist alongside Xcode 3, so I doubt there'd be any conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit the bullet and downloaded Xcode from the app store. Installed perfectly.